# Having trouble creating a grid in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Hi I am learning Java GUI's for the first time and I am having trouble creating a 28x28 grid for a project of mine. The problem I am having is that the panel that I am drawing the grid on is not being resized to the 720 by 720 pixels size that I want and it is not drawing the grid.

Here is my code that I have right now:

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{
    public DrawPanel()
    {
        super();
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setSize(720, 720);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();
        System.out.println(width + " " + height);

        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawGrid(g);
    }

    public void drawGrid(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(5, 5, 715, 5);

        for (int row = 0; row < 28; row++)
        {
            g.drawLine(20, 25 * (row + 1), 700, 25 * (row + 1));
        }
        for(int col = 0; col < 28; col++)
        {
            g.drawLine(25 * (col + 1), 20, 25 * (col + 1), 700);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You need to override the panel's `getPreferredSize` method and supply the `Dimension` you would prefer the panel to be

Comment: It is working now, thanks for your help.